# Create Custom Docker Alpine Image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am creating a customize Dockerfile by installing few drawing packages. I cannot install libgdiplus-dev package in Dockerfile. I have tried adding a mirror URL https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/armhf/libgdiplus- (mirrors can be found in this URL) dev in the Dockerfile but it did not help.

```
FROM alpine:3.7  
RUN apk add --no-cache libgdiplus-dev
```

Running above command ends me up saying

```
libgdiplus-dev (missing):  
required by: world[libgdiplus-dev]
```

Answer (score 7):

Found it. You can install any packages by giving repository as a parameter.

```
FROM alpine:3.7  
RUN apk add libgdiplus-dev --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use develop version of packages use alpine image version **edge**

Comment: I am sorry. I did not get you. Could you please explain.

Comment: @IsuruAmarathunga I think what she is saying is if you use alpine:edge the repo will be included in the image so you can just install the package.